# MVC4 Multiple Edit Views one Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am looking at a scenario in mvc4 where I have separate edit views for same model.  For example I split customer details into 3 groups and I create an edit view for each group.  so you can edit only the fields in a group at a time. In each view I add the other values as hidden.  I have been able to achieve up to this stage.  But the problem is how to set the controller and also how to redirect the form back to the originating view  if there is an error or some required fields  have not been supplied.

Any suggestions and help will be highly appreciated